# Predicting new points using mean and std_deviation of the model

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, mean, prediction, unsupervised-learning

I have mean and standard deviation both of shape(900*10) and I want to predict random number of points on same latent dimension of 10, How can I do that?

```
mean = numpy array from model of shape(900*10)
std_dev= numpy array from model of shape(900*10)
new_points_size=1000
new_points=np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std_dev, size=(new_points_size,10))
```

When I set new_points_size=900 I can get new_points but if it is set != 900 it throws error. What if I need to find other number of points which is not equal to 900?Please suggest me idea on this

Comment: What kind of model do you have?

Comment: @LucaAnzalone its GPLVM model that reduces high dimensional data to lower dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You have 900 * 10 different distributions. So if you want to sample only some of them then you will have to choose which one.

`new_points=np.random.normal(loc=mean[3, 4], scale=std_dev[3, 4])`

Or maybe you intend to average over the first dimension?

`new_points=np.random.normal(loc=np.mean(mean, dim=0), scale=np.mean(std_dev, dim=0), size=[10, other_number])`